# How to use exoplayer to play an mp4 while i'm downloading it from a local proxy?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

I have a problem with audio and video. I would like to play an mp4 while I'm downloading from another device. So, I have a proxy that performs this work:
download the file and at the same time send it to `exoplayer`.
For mp3 files it works, but for mp4 files it does not work.

How can I use `exoplayer` to solve this problem?

Comment: If you have found solution, please answer it